# WSO2 Governance Registry - Error Creating registry extension file (RXT)

Tags: wso2

```
When I am trying to upload the registry extension file (RXT) as Add resource - Create text content, I am getting the following error
```

Failed to add resource
     with text based content to path /_system/governance/repository/components/org.w
    so2.carbon.governance/types/myuri.rxt. An exception occurred while executing han
    dler chain. java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B

```
I even tried to copy the same contents from an exisitng RXT for API or URI and tried to upload it and got the same error

I also referred to the Issue Tracker sample around creating extensions, still got the same error
```

Comment: Here is the error that I am getting. Can anyone help me on this? I am on WSO2 governance registry version 4.5.0 Failed to add Text content. "Failed to add resource with text based content to path /_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/types/myuri.rxt. An exception occurred while executing handler chain. java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get this error when trying to upload the RXT file via the management console? If so, please try adding the RXT file to the following location:
G-Reg_home/repository/resources/rxts

Comment: Thanks, How do I make it show up on the left side menu under APIs/URIs?

Comment: It should appear in the menu once you log out and log in again to the management console.

Comment: I signed out and signed in that did not help, it is still not showing up in the left side menu. I also stopped and restarted the server, that did not help either, still not seeing it in the menu

Comment: Just got it to working. I had few unrelated problems (I had two versions of WSO2 and I was adding the rxt in the wrong location, and the schema for the rxt was incorrect ). It is workign now! Thanks a lot for your help on this!